Custom icons for radio buttons? BL4
Here's how i create preview collection:
preview_collections = {}
dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")

pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()

for entry in os.scandir(dir):
    if entry.name.endswith(".png"):
        name = os.path.splitext(entry.name)[0]
        pcoll.load(name.upper(), entry.path, "IMAGE")

Register and unregister:
def register():
    global preview_collections
    preview_collections = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")
    for entry in os.scandir(icons_dir):
        if entry.name.endswith(".png"):
            name = os.path.splitext(entry.name)[0]
            preview_collections.load(name.upper(), entry.path, "IMAGE")

def unregister():
    global preview_collections
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(preview_collections)
    preview_collections = None

Example of using custom icon for operator:
col.operator("object.my_operator", text="Copy", icon_value=pcoll['TEST_IC'].icon_id)

This one works fine and icon appear as expected.
But how i should deal with adding icon to EnumProperty?
My approaches of using simply icon name (i.e. file name) or similar code "icon_value=pcoll['TEST_IC'].icon_id" doesnt seems to work.

Is "BL4" supposed to indicate it's Blender version 4.0?

Yes, its blender 4. Specifically 4.0.2 in my case.

"BL" is not really used to mean Blender and specifying version as only the first number is not really useful. That's unnecessarily confusing. I would recommend not to do this if you want people to understand what you are talking about. Specify the full version like  Blender 4.0 or Blender 4.0.2. Third digit is usually for fix releases, so that can be omitted as it should not change any functionality. Please don't call Blender "BL". That's just confusing, nobody does that...
